# What am I missing in the logic of the code I am attaching below?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the following pattern in C++:

```
        1
      1 2
    1 2 3
  1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4
    1 2 3
      1 2
        1
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int i, j,k;

   for(i=-4;i<=4;i++)
   {

       for(j=1;j<(2*abs(i)); j++)
        cout<< " ";
       for(k=1; k<6-abs(i);k++)
        cout <<k;

   }
}
```

I'm having issues with moving to the next line.

Comment: Print a newline somewhere?

Comment: You need 3 changes, add new line, add space between numbers, and an extra small fix.

Comment: thanks guys made the changes

Comment: What issues? Explain what the current code does and why that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Newline has been missed in your code. print a new line once code escape from the second inner for loop. And also print a space after printing the number 'k'.

Please refer the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int i, j,k;

   for(i=-4; i<=4; i++)
   {

       for(j=1;j<(2*abs(i)); j++)
       {
            cout<< " ";
       }
       for(k=1; k<6-abs(i);k++)
       {
            cout <<k << " ";
       }
        
        cout << endl;

   }
}
```

Comment: `\n` is preferrable to `std::endl` when you do not want to flush.

Answer (score 0):

There were couple of issues in your code, such as:

1. New line was missing: after each row, put a newline.
2. Space were missing after printing each row.
3. Counter for `j` was not correct.

The following code solves the problems:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int i, j,k;

   for(i=-4;i<=4;i++) {
       for(j=1; j<=(2*abs(i)); j++) cout<< " ";
       for(k=1; k<6-abs(i);k++) cout << k << " ";
       
       cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
        1
      1 2
    1 2 3
  1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4
    1 2 3
      1 2
        1
```

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
cout << endl;
```

at the end of the "for" block

Comment: _"the "for" block"_ is a bit ambigious here.

Comment: Not enough BTW [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b59f9ec201acd0c), need 2 more fixes.

Comment: @churill: it's a homework, so the guy is supposed to figure it out

Comment: @Jarod42: you're right, but he asked only for help with moving to the next line

Comment: `\n`is preferrable to `std::endl`when you do not want to flush.

Comment: std::endl is preferrable to \n if you need to use proper line ending for your platform, as it translates to \r (unix) or \n(windows)

Comment: @JiriVolejnik `std::endl` does not just translate to `\n`, it additionally causes a `std::flush`.

Comment: @Tom Gebel: Nobody denies that